# No Audio when streaming to Youtube from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, streaming

So I'm not able to get sound to youtube when streaming with ffmpeg.

The command I try to run;

```
ffmpeg \
 -f v4l2 \
 -vcodec h264 \
 -video_size 864x480 \
 -r 24 \
 -i /dev/video1 \
 -f alsa \
 -thread_queue_size 1024 \
 -ac 2 \
 -i plughw:CARD=C920,DEV=0 \
 -c:a aac \
 -filter:a "volume=1.5" \
 -b:a 128k \
 -ar 44100 \
 -vcodec copy \
 -b:v 2000k  \
 -r 24 \
 -g 48 \
 -x264opts no-scenecut \
 -bufsize 4096k \
 -maxrate 2048k \
 -f flv \
 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAM_KODE
```

if I switch out the rmtp stream, with a file, like test.flv.
And then I try to watch this with VLC I do get sound.

If I check the audio codec in VLC I do see that the codec is aac.
And as far as I can see from their [help pages](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?hl=en) it is aac that is the correct audio codec to send in.

I'm not sure how to continue debug this issue, and ideas on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I was able to get this to work. I used [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs)
to test my stream, I noticed that the sound was choppy, I removed the 
`-x264opts no-scenecut \` and `-ar 44100 \`, then I was able to see it on youtube